# What are the most appropriate boost::asio read/write methods to use for a game server?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost::asio to make a socket network.  The library has a number of different methods for sending and receiving data, each of which perform a similar task with a slight difference.

For sending data, boost provides the following functions:

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_send()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send/overload1.html)

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_write_some()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html)

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_write()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html)

And for receiving data, boost provides these functions:

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_receive()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive/overload2.html)

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_read_some()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html)

[boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::async_read()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html)

Out of these, which one(s) are the most appropriate to use for a game server, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async_read()` and `async_write()` free functions are composed operations. They are implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `async_read_some()` or `async_write_some()` methods.

The member functions may not transmit or receive all data before the asynchronous operation completes. You should use the free functions if you desire that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The question's already been answered, but it's also worth mentioning that `async_write_some` is exactly the same function as `async_send`, the naming is just there for consistency since "send" applies to sockets and "write" applies to streams.

Another important point to note is that the `async_write` free function is what Chris Kohlhoff calls a "composed operation", and this means that even though it returns immediately, it's not safe to call another `async_write` until the associated handler has been called - this can cause all sorts of problems if not anticipated.  The `async_write_some` function is lower level, and doesn't suffer from this.

Further reading: http://blog.think-async.com/2009/08/composed-operations-coroutines-and-code.html